# Why do all files and directories from my home directory appear in Desktop?

Tags: nautilus, .desktop

Suddenly I started seeing an icon for each file and directory from `~` in my Desktop.

The icons do nothing -- they do  not work to open these items.

If I rename one of these odd Desktop icons, the item in `~` is renamed as well. Likewise if I delete the icon.

Also, `ls` or  Nautulus on the Desktop directory correctly shows an empty listing.

How do I resolve this?

(Ubuntu 17.10)

Note that my `~/Desktop` is actually a link to `/data/Desktop`

This, however, worked fine until two days ago and I don't believe that it is the cause.

```
~$  cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my desktop the same as home folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523167/why-is-my-desktop-the-same-as-home-folder)

Comment: What does: `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` show? If this awry an answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/a/737236/57576

Comment: @andrew.46 I added that to the question. Does "$HOME/" indicate that the value is missing?

Comment: @andrew.46 Thank you! Please give an answer so I can accept. My question is similar to  the one you linked but the strange behavior of the icons perhaps means that it should be treated as non-duplicate.

Comment: @muru Indeed, that is similar. But the icon behavior is a an interesting clue added here.

Comment: Does it make a difference in solving the problem?

Comment: @JoshuaFox Good news is that hopefully you have rectified your issue and all is well on your setup now. Bad news is that the question probably should be marked as a duplicate so I will refrain from posting a formal answer.  But good to see the issue resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit  `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. You may find that all values are reset to `$HOME`. Edit it to something sane like this. Restart your windowing session (or just reboot).

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
#
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```