# all of my folders appeared on my desktop; how do I remove them

Tags: gnome, 18.04

I had nothing on my desktop except my dash, which is hidden, and docky; suddenly all of my folders are there and I have no idea why; can anyone tell me how to remove them?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l ~/Desktop`?

Comment: Is this any help: https://askubuntu.com/a/737236/57576 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the contents of your hidden configuration file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. (In your file manager, turn "Show Hidden Files" on. You now will see a folder `.config` in your home folder that contains the file `user-dirs.dirs`. Open it with a text editor.) There should be an entry for your desktop, which by default on Ubuntu read as:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
```

In your case, the entry probably simply points to `$HOME`, causing your entire home folder to display on the desktop. Just change the entry back as shown using a text editor.

You might have inadvertently changed the entry by deleting the Desktop folder at some point. Behind the screens, such actions update the `.config/user-dirs.dirs` file.