# All folders visible in desktop linux

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I have a problem where all the folders in my laptop are visible in my desktop, I tried following the instruction as suggested in [all of my folders appeared on my desktop; how do I remove them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050523/all-of-my-folders-appeared-on-my-desktop-how-do-i-remove-them/1507845#1507845) and made changes within the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` which is refelected temporarily, but the moment I restart my laptop the file gets reset back to just how it was i.e. `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"`.

Can anyone helpme in getting a permanent fix?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Kindly mention your Ubuntu version along with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Desktop icons can be disabled through the Extension Manager (if you want to learn more about it, a link I found helpful was https://itsfoss.com/extension-manager/ ).

To install the program, run:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

When you open it, you should see something like this:

[image: Extension Manager]

Go down to `System Extensions > Desktop Icons` and toggle the button to be disabled:

[image: Desktop Icons disabled]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. The issue was with my Desktop folder which got accidentally deleted(I don't know how it happened though). Fortunately, I tried simply restoring the desktop folder, and that resolved the issue.